# Duplicate hint without close votes

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262426/sql-server-cannot-insert-an-explicit-value-into-a-timestamp-column) contains a hint being a duplicate, but has no close votes.  If I recall correctly the close vote expired.

Should the duplicate hint disappear as well?

Answer (score 4):

The [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88069/sonny-boy) who "left" the comment does not have 3K rep, so unless they had a massive rep loss since May, the comment you are seeing is the result of a duplicate **flag**, not a comment.

As you can see if you click into the duplicate menu, the flag is still there.

[image]

Since close flags never expire, it will never age away until the flag is declined or the post is actually closed.

Answer (score 3):

No, the comment is only removed if the question is actually closed.

If a close vote has expired, you could flag it as obsolete. In this case it's a flag, not a vote; flags don't expire.

On the other hand, without much SQL Server expertise it *does* look to me like your question is a duplicate of the other post; the fact that the dupe votes were never followed up upon not withstanding.

Comment: Yes, maybe it is a duplicate. I was just curious about the notice.

Comment: Nope, not an expired vote.

Comment: @psubsee2003: If it was flagged, then it also has been and gone through the review queue by now. Enough time has passed for single close vote to have expired, in any case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but close flags do not expire.  If you actually click through to the duplicate menu (as per the screen shot in my image), the flag is still active.

Comment: @psubsee2003: right, it is indeed a flag. Yet if it *was* an expired close vote, the comment would still be there anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters correct, just stating that in this specific case, it is not an expired vote and it should not be flagged as obsolete.